Dockerized NestJS application only accepts GET request
I made a NestJS application and deployed into AWS lightsail using docker, and faced a weird situation.
I could see that the application runs correctly and I can connect to the application at the external of the container.
However, the weird situation is when I try to send POST request then it hangs up, but not when I try to send GET request. (And I did not happen when I tested it locally.)
Also when I checked the log of the container, I found that nothing happened when the POST request was made.
Here's the API document of my server: (deleted)
Here's the code of my Dockerfile:
# Step 1 Build
FROM node:lts AS builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Step 2 Application Start
FROM node:lts-alpine
ARG STAGE
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/.env.$STAGE ./.env
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "dist/src/main.js"]

Here's the code of my docker-compose:
version: '3'
services:
  node:
    container_name: backend-dev
    image: dokdo2005/freedea-api:development
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    restart: always
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres-dev
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=freedea
    volumes:
      - postgres-data-dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis:
    container_name: redis-dev
    image: redis:6.2.4-alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    restart: always
volumes:
    postgres-data-dev:

Is there anything wrong I made?

This mwill most likeyly be an issue with the hosting setup? Are you using nginx on the server?

@MelvinKosisochukwu Nope. I'm exposing port 80 directly from the NestJS application container.

Have you checked the CORS configuration? In that case, POST requests will hang

Please don't add things like "(Solved)" to question title (I've rolled that back). Also, don't add solutions to the question (though in this case I left it in, as it can also be considered debugging information). If you managed to solve your own problem, then post an answer and accept that after the timeout.

The main reason was that the server(backend-dev) always stops when the DB transaction starts, and I changed the base image in Dockerfile from node:lts-alpine to node:lts.
Then the problem was solved.
It seems that node:lts-alpine image has a compatibility issue with TypeORM and PostgreSQL.
